# Does downloading a word document attach any dates to it?

Tags: microsoft-word, gmail

If someone sends you a Word 2010 .docx via Gmail, will the time and date downloaded be recorded by the file somewhere? Or Gmail? Alternatively, are the only dates attached to files the creation, modification, and access dates?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer your question. The date create, date modify , access date will be recorded onto the file. So when you download it to your computer, the date create will be the day you download the file but the modify and access date will be earlier.

Comment: great, that's what i wanted to know! so there are no other attributes recording the date creation?

Comment: @Richard, some documents may contain a CREATEDATE field which displays the date the document was created.

Answer (score 0):

A downloaded file will have creation, modification, and access timestamps recorded. Often, these will all be set to approximately the date/time of download, although if your download client receives the original modification date/time from the file server, then it may record that instead of the download date/time. Note that these timestamps are recorded at the file system level (that is, any downloaded file would have such timestamps, not just .docx files).

Microsoft Office documents also have internal timestamps that are part of the document file itself; these timestamps are separate from and in addition to the file system timestamps. These internal timestamps would not be updated by the act of downloading the file.